# How can I change the root namespace for scripts in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#, visual-studio-code

How can I change the root namespace for scripts in Unity?

I went to `Edit` - `Project Settings...` - `Editor` - `Root namespace` and put there the `gameplay` value.

I checked that the `Assembly-CSharp.csproj` has the `<RootNamespace>gameplay</RootNamespace>`

Now I go to VS Code editor, create a class and the class still uses a wrong namespace. What may I be missing here?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you creating the scripts from Unity? I guess creating directly from VS doesn't work. The root namespace is a Unity setting that is applied to each new script created. I tested it now, I renamed my current namespace and it works.

Comment: @Xriuk, creating a script from Unity does not add namespace at all.

Comment: When I create it from Unity it creates a new MonoBehaviour class in the correct namespace for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Jetbrains Rider there is one option on folder properties named "Namespace provider" when we use a right-click mouse on the folder. Just uncheck that check box and the namespaces work as expected. You can use this for the Project and Scripts folders.

I'm not sure if VS Code has this option.

**Two good videos for namespaces in Unity:**

- [Should You Use Namespaces in Unity? (Code Review)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pfiZVTDhWyM)
- [Namespaces in Unity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLrGdx-Ob3g)